# error expected )

Tags: c

Hi can u help me with my codes:

```
    typedef struct term{
        char var[10];
        int val[8];
    }TERM;

    TERM termx[50];
    int initialize();
    int a[15],b[15],c[15];

    int check(TERM termx[].var[],int i){
    int j;
    const char* const StringArray[NrOfStrings] =
        {
      "ABC","ABC'","AB'C'","A'B'C'","A'B'C","A'BC'","AB'C",
      "AB+C","A'B'+C'","A'B'+C","A'B+C'","AB'+C'","AB'+C","
      "A+BC","A'+B'C'","A'+B'C","A'+BC'","A+B'C'","A+B'C",
        };
    for(j=0;j<NrOfStrings;j++){
        if(stcmp(term[i].var,StringArray[j])==0){
            return(j);
            break;
            }
        }

    }
void main(){
int x,i,j,key;
char y[10];
    initialize();
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("Enter the %d term: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",termx[i].var);
            for(j=0;j<strlen(termx[i].var);j++)
                termx[i].var[j]=changeToupper(termx[i].var[j],i,j);
        key=check(termx[i].var,i);
       }   
    printf("\nA\tB\tC\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",a[i],b[i],c[i]);
    getch();

}
```

it gives me the expected ')' error and its pointing to the parameter of the function check(). i know that it is a common error  but i tried searching google but can't find solution. i hope u can help me with it.thanks

Comment: s/stcmp/strcmp/ ?? BTW: main() should return int.

Comment: Please make a better indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
int check(TERM termx[].var[],int i){
```

should be something like

```
int check(TERM *term,int i){
```

Then

```
key=check(termx[i].var,i);
```

should read

```
key=check(termx[i],i);
```

Comment: but is it not valid? im trying to pass the specific value of  termx[].var[]?